# Time stamped SQL storage of changing data types

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, normalization

I need to store various time stamped data parameters in a SQL database.  See below for typical non-normalized data where I show five analog values (room temperature, room humidity, swimming pool pH, AHU supply temperature, and room pressure), and one binary value (light status).

Different "customers" will own the data which I indicated below with the "address" field.  Often a given parameter to be stored will be added or removed.  Also, often a new variable which hasn't previously been archived (i.e. chilled water supply temperature) will be added, and it is impossible to know beforehand which parameters might be required to be stored in the future.

A typical query will be to return the temperature in 123 Main Street Room 102 over a given time span.  Another typical query will be to return the temperature, humidity, and light level in all rooms in 123 Main Street.

Adding columns to the table for each desired parameter obviously does not make sense.  But I also struggle with storing different type of data in the same column.  I also struggle how I duplicate the room number in many of the parameters and feel it should be normalized, however, other parameters don't have an associated room number, so I don't know how this will work.  I also question whether I should create a table who's PK is a composite of the building and the timestamp, and join another table which has columns for the parameter and value (and maybe the type).

How should this data be modeled?

```
+------------------+-----------------+------------------------+-------+
|     Address      |    Timestamp    |       Parameter        | Value |
+------------------+-----------------+------------------------+-------+
| 123 Main Street  | 7/13/2015 16:00 | Room 101 Temperature   | 70.99 |
| 123 Main Street  | 7/13/2015 16:00 | Room 101 Humidity      | 50%   |
| 123 Main Street  | 7/13/2015 16:00 | Room 101 Light Status  | Off   |
| 123 Main Street  | 7/13/2015 16:00 | Room 102 Temperature   | 70.90 |
| 123 Main Street  | 7/13/2015 16:00 | Room 102 Humidity      | 50%   |
| 123 Main Street  | 7/13/2015 16:00 | Room 102 Light Status  | Off   |
| 123 Main Street  | 7/13/2015 16:00 | Room 103 Temperature   | 69.95 |
| 123 Main Street  | 7/13/2015 16:00 | Room 103 Humidity      | 49%   |
| 123 Main Street  | 7/13/2015 16:00 | Room 103 Light Status  | Off   |
| 123 Main Street  | 7/13/2015 16:15 | Room 101 Temperature   | 69.65 |
| 123 Main Street  | 7/13/2015 16:15 | Room 101 Humidity      | 47%   |
| 123 Main Street  | 7/13/2015 16:15 | Room 101 Light Status  | On    |
| 123 Main Street  | 7/13/2015 16:15 | Room 102 Temperature   | 69.18 |
| 123 Main Street  | 7/13/2015 16:15 | Room 102 Humidity      | 46%   |
| 123 Main Street  | 7/13/2015 16:15 | Room 102 Light Status  | On    |
| 123 Main Street  | 7/13/2015 16:15 | Room 103 Temperature   | 68.49 |
| 123 Main Street  | 7/13/2015 16:15 | Room 103 Humidity      | 48%   |
| 123 Main Street  | 7/13/2015 16:15 | Room 103 Light Status  | On    |
| 123 Main Street  | 7/13/2015 16:30 | Room 101 Temperature   | 68.93 |
| 123 Main Street  | 7/13/2015 16:30 | Room 101 Humidity      | 49%   |
| 123 Main Street  | 7/13/2015 16:30 | Room 101 Light Status  | On    |
| 123 Main Street  | 7/13/2015 16:30 | Room 102 Temperature   | 69.44 |
| 123 Main Street  | 7/13/2015 16:30 | Room 102 Humidity      | 49%   |
| 123 Main Street  | 7/13/2015 16:30 | Room 102 Light Status  | Off   |
| 123 Main Street  | 7/13/2015 16:30 | Room 103 Temperature   | 69.63 |
| 123 Main Street  | 7/13/2015 16:30 | Room 103 Humidity      | 48%   |
| 123 Main Street  | 7/13/2015 16:30 | Room 103 Light Status  | Off   |
| 321 Front Street | 7/14/2015 14:00 | AHU Supply Temperature | 69.96 |
| 321 Front Street | 7/14/2015 14:00 | Swimming Pool PH       | 7.19  |
| 321 Front Street | 7/14/2015 14:00 | Room 101 Pressure      | 0.11  |
| 321 Front Street | 7/14/2015 14:15 | AHU Supply Temperature | 69.92 |
| 321 Front Street | 7/14/2015 14:15 | Swimming Pool PH       | 6.97  |
| 321 Front Street | 7/14/2015 14:15 | Room 101 Pressure      | 0.11  |
| 321 Front Street | 7/14/2015 14:30 | AHU Supply Temperature | 70.37 |
| 321 Front Street | 7/14/2015 14:30 | Swimming Pool PH       | 6.84  |
| 321 Front Street | 7/14/2015 14:30 | Room 101 Pressure      | 0.12  |
| 321 Front Street | 7/14/2015 14:45 | AHU Supply Temperature | 70.80 |
| 321 Front Street | 7/14/2015 14:45 | Swimming Pool PH       | 6.70  |
| 321 Front Street | 7/14/2015 14:45 | Room 101 Pressure      | 0.12  |
| 321 Front Street | 7/14/2015 15:00 | AHU Supply Temperature | 71.29 |
| 321 Front Street | 7/14/2015 15:00 | Swimming Pool PH       | 6.90  |
| 321 Front Street | 7/14/2015 15:00 | Room 101 Pressure      | 0.12  |
| 321 Front Street | 7/14/2015 15:15 | AHU Supply Temperature | 72.13 |
| 321 Front Street | 7/14/2015 15:15 | Swimming Pool PH       | 7.13  |
| 321 Front Street | 7/14/2015 15:15 | Room 101 Pressure      | 0.11  |
| 321 Front Street | 7/14/2015 15:30 | AHU Supply Temperature | 72.84 |
| 321 Front Street | 7/14/2015 15:30 | Swimming Pool PH       | 7.01  |
| 321 Front Street | 7/14/2015 15:30 | Room 101 Pressure      | 0.11  |
| 321 Front Street | 7/14/2015 15:45 | AHU Supply Temperature | 72.82 |
| 321 Front Street | 7/14/2015 15:45 | Swimming Pool PH       | 7.22  |
| 321 Front Street | 7/14/2015 15:45 | Room 101 Pressure      | 0.11  |
| 321 Front Street | 7/14/2015 16:00 | AHU Supply Temperature | 72.23 |
| 321 Front Street | 7/14/2015 16:00 | Swimming Pool PH       | 7.40  |
| 321 Front Street | 7/14/2015 16:00 | Room 101 Pressure      | 0.11  |
+------------------+-----------------+------------------------+-------+
```

Comment: have a column with `type` to store `room temperature, room humidity, swimming pool pH, AHU supply temperature, room pressure` and `room` as another column, so it will be easier to maintain and query

Comment: there are different values for the same measure at the same timestamp?will this always be the case?

Comment: If you always query all data at once (so everything for 1 room at once), you could consider storing the data as 1 record per room with a JSON (XML or other) structure for the real data.

Comment: @vkp. Regarding you second comment, for a given parameter/location and time stamp, there will only be one value.  I might have had some errors in my sample data

Comment: Normalization is the way to go for your case. The columns would be `address`, `timestamp`, `room_id`, `parameter`, `value`. Make the value column `varchar` so you can store `on/off` as well as  `decimals`.

Comment: @vkp.  Regarding your first comment.  The user is responsible to add parameters to be trended.  As such, they will need to add add the `type` value which will likely get quickly out of control.  Also, what does this `type` value get me?  As for as `room`, again, might get out of control, and what if it isn't quite a room, but something like "3rd floor stairwell" or "elementary school play yard"?

Comment: i think storing it in a `json` format makes more sense than storing in a relational database as you don't have control of the values in the columns. `mongodb` maybe?

Comment: @vkp  Regarding your third comment.  Yes, maybe so... `room_id` maybe should define location (i.e. `Room 101` or `Swimming Pool`)?  Probably should normalize `address` and `timestamp` as a separate table?  Still doesn't seem right...

Comment: Typically, storing multiple data in a given table is frowned upon.  Also, no indexes would exist on say `room 101 temperature`.

Comment: @user1032531..yes. let me know what you decide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with 3 tables:

```
Address
-------
address_id
address_name

Location
--------
location_id
location_name
address_id

Measurement
-----------
meauserment_id
location_id
type
timestamp
value
```

Here all rooms, swimming pools and supplies are modeled as different locations, so types will be just "Temperature", "Humidity", etc.

For your queries you would need to have a composite secondary index on `(location_id, type, timestamp)`.

If you can have a lot of locations for the same address and you really care about read performance for your second type of queries, then (assuming you can allow yourself to ignore multiple datapoints of the same location_id-type per timestamp) the best way to organize measurements would be:

```
Measurement
-----------
address_id
location_id
type
timestamp
value
```

where your PK would be `(address_id, location_id, type, timestamp)` + a secondary index `(location_id, type, timestamp)`.

Comment: You can probably simply have 5 columns for the 5 metrics.  Temperature could be a `FLOAT`; humidity could be a `TINYINT UNSIGNED`; etc.  Doing this will simplify the code.